# How to integrate a static frontend and Django?

Tags: python, django

I have an HTML page being served up by Apache2. Then I have an Ajax call that is supposed to call to a Python script, which calculates some values. Then Django is supposed to return the values as an Httpresponse().

I am wondering if there is a problem with the HTML page not being a Django template. If so, what should I do about it?

Comment: No problem, just have Apache serve the static content and pass the requests that need dynamic responses to django.

Comment: @DanielB, How would I have Apache pass it to Django? (n00b to Django)

Comment: Depends on what's available. mod_wsgi is the recommended choice, but it is also possible to use fast_cgi